# How to make query for elasticsearch in spring boot like we do in sense plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, sense

this is query which i have done in sense

```
GET /_search?q=2016
```

it searches in whole db and get results for all entries which has "2016" in any field.

Comment: There is a java api for the same. You can use that..

Comment: yup , there is java api for it but it is for regular search but here i want to do full text search ,here i'm stuck. here is a link  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/search-lite.html#all-field-intro

Answer (score 0):

Giving `q` as query paramater run as `query string` query. So you have to use java api for `Query String`. You can use :

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("index_name")
    .setTypes("type1Name")
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryString("2016"))                 
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```